# How to calculate the cosine similarity of two vectors in PySpark?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I am about to compute the cosine similarity of two vectors in PySpark, like

```
1 - spatial.distance.cosine(xvec, yvec)
```

but scipy seems to not support the pyspark.ml.linalg.Vector type.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `dot` and `norm` methods to calculate this pretty easily:

```
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
x = Vectors.dense([1,2,3])
y = Vectors.dense([2,3,5])

1 - x.dot(y)/(x.norm(2)*y.norm(2))
# 0.0028235350472619603
```

---

With *scipy*:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine
​
x = np.array([1,2,3])
y = np.array([2,3,5])

cosine(x, y)
# 0.0028235350472619603
```

Comment: @Psidom Why can't I apply it to whole vector-type columns?
Something like this
`df_new = df_with_vectors.select("vector1", "vector2", "vector1.dot(vector2)/(vector1.norm(2)*vector2.norm(2)) as norm_src")` 
gives an error of `need struct type but got vector`.